# Calling modal window by click on item in menu

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing web app on **ASP.NET WebForms**.On client-side I'm using **Twitter Bootstrap**.

I know how to call modal window by click on a button,etc, but I have no idea how to call a modal window when I click on item in my menu.

Menu

- item1
- item2

Click on item1 --> calling modal window A

Click on item2 --> calling modal window B

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the modal with jquery. So you would hook up an on click event to your list item and call the `.modal()` function when the list item is clicked. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#first').on('click', function() {    //<-- this would be your list item.
        $('#myModal').modal();              //<-- this would be your modal.
    });
 });
```

You would repeat the on click event above for your second list item also.

And a jsFiddle to have a look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hvyty/

Alternatively, you could simply use an anchor tag in your menu:

```
<li>
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Menu item 1</a>
</li>
```